# Kendo UI Treeview append function Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

It looks like the performance of the following function is really bad.

```
treeView.append(children, parent);
```

Here *treeView* is Kendo UI Treeview, *parent* is container node for children and *children* is array of approximately 150 new nodes (my scenario).

And this code executes more than 7 seconds.

I guess the *append* function is not well implemented for a collection of items, so maybe there are some workarounds with generating html through jQuery, but Kendo UI Treeview should also know about new nodes to process future expand events for new nodes correctly.
Is there any way to improve the performance of the code above?

Thank you,
Ihor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who encounter this problem:

Eventually I investigated Kendo UI source codes and instead of line from original post I used following code:

```
 treeView.dataItem(parent).children.data(children)
```

That worked fine in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Performance is a pretty relative term. If it takes 7 seconds, of course, it's not a good performance. In my computer `append` 150 new nodes took about one second but anyway I might suggest you some improvements.

How do you `append` the nodes, one by one?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    var added = { text:"node" + i };
    tree.append(added, parent);
}
```

try this instead (build an array with all the nodes to add and then invoke `append`):

```
var added = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    added.push({ text: "node" + i });
}
tree.append(added, parent);
```

In my computer it went from 1105ms to 787. Not that much but ...

**BUT**, this is the time for inserting the nodes not the time that is needed for rendering. Is your problem `append` or render it on screen?

Comment: Yes, just one line (from my original post) executes 7 seconds.
Actually I tried both of your samples, and both the same time. I investigated kendo sources a bit and found that the following line executes much faster
treeView.dataItem(parent).children.data(children)
Can you answer what problems may occur if using this approach?